# React - child component not setting state on parent?

Tags: reactjs

I have an App parent component, and a child Create component.

I read from other threads in SO that I have to create a method that sets state on the parent component, and pass it to the child as props.

In my case, I have a method called `post` in parent, and passed to the child Create component, which is called when a button is clicked.

When the button is clicked, turns out that it cant even read state because its undefined.
Appreciate any input I could get.

Parent Component

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        products: []
    }

    post(name){ //post method to be passed into Create component as props
        return axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/api/products/${uuidv4()}`, {id: uuidv4(), name: name })
        .then(res => this.setState({products: [res.data, ...products]})) //console.log(this.state) will return Cannot read property state of undefined.
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

    render(){
        const {products} = this.state;       
        return( //pass this.post to Create component
            <div>
                <Create post={this.post}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Child Component

```
class Create extends React.Component {
    state = {
        inputValue: '',
    }

    updateInput(value){
        this.setState({inputValue: value});
    }

    render(){
        const {inputValue} = this.state;
        const {post} = this.props; //destructure post method from App component
        return( // called post method inside the button onClick
        <div className='form'>
            <input type='text' value={inputValue} onChange={(event)=>this.updateInput(event.target.value)}/>
            <button onClick={() => post(inputValue)}>Create</button> 
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your parent component change it like this:

```
<Create post={(input) => {
    this.post(input);
}}/>
```

The reason you need to do that is that the way `post` is being invoked in the child component means it's not "scoped" to your parent component.

Comment: Thank you for this. I assume that when you try to pass a method to a child, you have to pass an argument (such as input in your example) in order to 'bind' and 'scope' the method to the parent, when that method is called by the child? I hope that question made sense.

Comment: One idiomatic way of doing it is in your constructor:

`this.doPost = this.post.bind(this);` and then pass `doPost` to your `Create` component.

Comment: Ah gotcha, that makes sense. Much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
const post = (name) => {
    ....
}
```

(use an arrow function to not use bind on that function in the component constructor)

```
<button onClick={() => post(this.state.inputValue)}>Create</button>
```

(I think is required this.state to retrieve the inputValue state property)